# mailkit imap client Inbox.MoveTo "The folder is not currently open in read-write mode."

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I am having an issue moving mail out of the inbox to a subfolder on the mail server using the MailKit/MimeKit tools.  Currently I can read email in either folder, as well as delete email from either folder.  The mail server is microsoft exchange 365.  I am not currently having any issue with any imap function using the Mozilla Thunderbird client.  My code is as follows:

```
public void MoveEmail(string index, string folder)
{
    using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
    {
        client.Connect(ServerUrl, ServerPort, true);
        client.Authenticate(UserName, Password);
        client.Inbox.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        if (!client.Inbox.IsOpen == true)
            throw new Exception("Inbox is not open.");

        var dingle = client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(folder);
        dingle.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        if (!dingle.IsOpen == true)
            throw new Exception("Dingle is not open.");

        client.Inbox.MoveTo(0, dingle);

        var dangle = dingle.Count;
        var wingle = dingle.Fetch(0, -1, MailKit.MessageSummaryItems.Full);

        dingle.Close(false);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

The code executes all the way through until it hits the move statement, then it throws an exception:  "The folder is not currently open in read-write mode."

Thanks for reading!
Carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once you open the `dingle` folder, it closes the `Inbox` folder. This is how IMAP works (it can only have 1 folder open at a time).

The solution is to not open the `dingle` folder, just open the `Inbox` folder.

The code should look like this:

```
public void MoveEmail(string index, string folder)
{
    using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
    {
        client.Connect(ServerUrl, ServerPort, true);
        client.Authenticate(UserName, Password);
        client.Inbox.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        if (!client.Inbox.IsOpen == true)
            throw new Exception("Inbox is not open.");

        var dingle = client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(folder);

        client.Inbox.MoveTo(0, dingle);

        dingle.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        if (!dingle.IsOpen == true)
            throw new Exception("Dingle is not open.");

        var dangle = dingle.Count;
        var wingle = dingle.Fetch(0, -1, MailKit.MessageSummaryItems.Full);

        dingle.Close(false);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: You still have to open the `dingle` folder before you can use the Count property or the Fetch() method.

Comment: Yeah, those are legacy of troubleshooting and I've just removed them.  It did cause me a brief bit of confusion when trying to access the count threw an error, but I sorted out that I didn't need that or the fetch in this method, thanks again!